# No Error from Script for Non-Existent File

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sh

I have a shell script that reads a text file and uses its content. So far so good. But now I'm trying to make the script exit if the file is not found. The script looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash

function errorcatcher() {
  errorcode=$?
  echo "ERROR CODE : ${errorcode}"
  exit ${errorcode}
}

trap errorcatcher ERR

MYFILE=$1

IFS='|'

while read line; do
  echo ${line}
done < ${MYFILE}

echo "Execution complete"
```

And I run the script as

```
sh myscript.sh /home/mydir/ABC.txt
```

and it works fine. But if I try this

```
sh myscript.sh /home/mydir/nonexisting.file
```

I get

```
myscript.sh: line 17: /home/mydir/nonexisting.file: No such file or directory
Execution complete
```

Function `errorcatcher` does not get invoked and instead of exiting with an error code, the execution continues and I get the line `Execution complete` even though the file in question doesn't exist. My guess is no error is generated here, so I added this line before reading the text file

```
ls ${MYFILE}
```

The `errorcatcher` gets invoked this time. But if I try

```
sh myscript.sh /home/mydir/ABC.tx
```

Instead of existing file `ABC.txt`, I pass its incomplete name `ABC.tx` and again, the `errorcatcher` function is not invoked and the script completes successfully (`Execution complete` gets echoed).

Could someone help me with this? I'm curious as to why `errorcatcher` doesn't get invoked

1. for a non existing file without `ls`
2. for incomplete file name (ABC.tx) with `ls`

Comment: file suffixes are arbitrary, there is nothing incomplete about `ABC.tx`. Does running with `set -x` give any insight

Comment: @jenesaisquoi No.The `ls` just gives me `/home/mydir/ABC.tx`, then the script echoes `Execution complete`

Comment: @Amber, it's strange enough that the ls execution does not fail with a non existing file as argument. Are you sure /home/mydir/ABC.tx does not exist? In my test with your script, ls fails and prints "No such file or directory". Also the script catches the error and prints ERROR CODE: 2. About the 1st question if you remove ls but you sorround the while loop between two parenthesis (while ... done) < ${MYFILE} you would get the same effect. I believe it's because bash traces its children processes. Also, you probably want echo $line, not echo line.

Comment: @matteomartelli  `/home/mydir/ABC.tx` does not exist. `/home/mydir/ABC.txt`, however, does. I'll try surrounding it with parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

> Function `errorcatcher` does not get invoked …

Indeed, with an error in the redirection of a loop like

```
while read line; do
  …
done < ${MYFILE}
```

the `ERR` trap is not invoked. You have discovered an undocumented exception in the implementation of the `trap` command, or, if you prefer, a bug.

You can evade that by adding an additional test of the redirection before the `while`, e. g. the line

```
<$MYFILE
```

on its own will invoke the error trap.